# Is `git commit --amend` touching more files than is necessary?

Tags: git, git-commit, build-system, git-amend

I often experience the following:

1. Modify files A, B, and C.
2. Commit the modifications with `git commit`.
3. Build the project, so the build is up to date.
4. Make a follow-up / fix-up modification to file A only.
5. Run `git commit -a --amend` (or `git commit --amend path/to/A`)
6. Rebuild the project incrementally.

Now, since I've only modified file A since the last time I've built, I would expect that only file A gets rebuilt, but what I invariably see is that all of A, B, and C (i.e., all the files touched by the entire commit) are rebuilt.

It seems to me that `git commit --amend` it `touch`ing / bumping the last modified timestamps of each of A, B, and C, even though I'm only adding a modification of A to the commit.

**Is this necessary? Can it be avoided, so only A is touched and only A gets rebuilt?**

If it matters, my project is in C++ and my build system is cmake+ninja, but I think that's largely besides the point as it's fairly standard for build systems to rely on last modified timestamps to determine what to rebuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git commit` does not touch *any* files in your work-tree.  It does not matter whether you use `--amend` here.

A `git commit` without `-a` does not *use* any files from your work-tree either, but `git commit -a` has Git, in effect, run `git add -u` first, which will *read* some files from the work-tree in order to copy them into the index.  Then, either way—with or without `-a`—`git commit` builds the new commit from whatever is in the index.

The new commit, once made, has some new, unique, never-seen-before hash ID.  If you're doing a normal `git commit` (without `--amend`), you have some series of commits in your repository, each with its own unique hash ID, with the *last* such commit having some hash ID `H`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
```

(Here, the uppercase letters stand in for the actual raw hash IDs, which look random, but really aren't, but also aren't predictable.)  The new commit acquires its new unique hash ID `I`, and inside `I`, the stored parent hash ID is `H`.  Git writes the new ID into the branch name, giving:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
```

With `--amend`, the difference is that instead of having new commit `I` point back to existing commit `H`, Git constructs the new commit with the *same* parent that `H` has, in this case `G`.  The effect is that `H` is shoved off to the side:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G--I   <-- your-branch (HEAD)
```

The existing commit `H` is unchanged, but it appears to vanish: it's not findable by starting at `I` and working backwards.  So `git log` *hides* it, and it seems to be gone, as if Git has somehow changed `H`.  Git hasn't; `H` is still intact.  It's also still recoverable for at least 30 days by default, as the hash ID is stored in what Git calls the *reflogs*.  But it *looks* gone.

If you are seeing various files get rebuilt, this is not because Git itself touched the source files.  Something else may have touched the source files, or—my guess, but just a guess—your build system may mark them as dependent on the specific Git commit hash: since `I` has a different hash than `H`, and the build artifacts were a consequence of `H` not `I`, they are now out of date.

(Other possibilities include Git hooks that change timestamps on files, of course.)

Comment: Huh, you're right. It appers the build system looks at the git hash and embeds it in some files, and this is what causes more files than just the modified ones to get rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid that (manually) is to do all the commits without amending and, when you are done with the changes, [rebase interactively](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history#interactive-rebase) squashing the commits (the ones that you are amending now)